# How to insert data into mysql database using laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel and I want to insert data into the database.

```
class Test1Controller extends Controller {
public function index(Request $req)
{
    $item = $req->input('item');
    $name = $req->input('name');
    $data=array('item'=>$item,'name'=>$name);
    DB::table('test1')->insert($data)

    $view = view('common.test1');
    $obj = DB::table('test1')->get();
    $view->obj = $obj;
    return $view;
}
```

and this is my route file code

```
Route::post('/test/test1/index/','Controller@index');
```

I got an error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::input()

Comment: eh, thats weird, could you share the Laravel version? `php artisan --version`. also i am not sure why, you had `Test1Controller` but your route fires to `Controller`.

Answer (score 0):

try to include this library at the top of your controller

use Illuminate\Http\Request;